# Rename multiple files in one directory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is it possible to rename all the files in a folder with a simple program using vb.NET

Lets say there is a folder containing the files, files are vary every time loaded:

A123.txt
B456.txt
C567.txt

Will it be possible to rename these files in one operation,as below:

A_1.txt
B_2.txt
B_3.txt

Comment: It is possible. You just need to find a clear rule on how the new name is generated based on the original name.

Comment: @the_lotus thanks for your reply please descibe in details and code how to create a rule to handle the above

Comment: @HansUp Sorry it was modified

Comment: I can't... It seems like C567.txt should be renamed to B_3.txt, I don't know why it's the case.

Comment: @the_lotus let say the file name is customer123.txt and want to change it to be customer.txt, the code should ignore the old file name and do change based on some words only is it clear now?

Comment: I think the_lotus is trying to say that we don't know your numbering rule. Only you can know that and then you need to code to it. The only thing I would add as a recommendation is that once you know your rule, you do a check to see if there are any files that DONT follow the rule before running a rename against it. Then, as you are running the rule, make sure you are not re-using a name you just previously processed in that folder.

Comment: @DrDoomPDX There is no rule for numbering the original file come with timestamp and I want the new file to be renamed without timestamp just tell me the code that should be used to handle it or should I use multi threading for this case

Comment: `in one operation` no, System.IO is your Namespace for file operations and there's nothing I know of in there which can do this in a single operation. But you can write a loop or use "multi threading" as you suggested.

Comment: The DirectoryInfo class of System.IO will return the files of that directory with the GetFiles() method. From that, you can iterate through the files and use the File class / Move() method to rename the file. But upon that renaming process (before doing it), check to see if you already renamed another file to the name you are about to use. The File.Exists method will keep you safe.

Answer (score 0):

This could be simplified but here is the long version with comments every step of the way

```
Imports System.IO


' get your filenames to be renamed
Dim filenames = Directory.GetFiles("c:\path\with\files")
' order them by whatever rule you choose (here it is by modification date)
Dim orderedFilenames = filenames.OrderBy(Function(s) File.GetLastWriteTime(s))
' rename the files into a dictionary<oldname, newname>
' will result in filename X_Y.Z where X is first letter, Y is order index, Z is extension
Dim newNameSelector =
    Function(s As String, i As Integer)
        Return New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(s,
            Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(s), $"{Path.GetFileName(s)(0)}_{i}{Path.GetExtension(s)}"))
    End Function
' get new names using the newNameSelector function
Dim newNames = orderedFilenames.Select(newNameSelector)
' define the operation to rename the file using a keyvaluepair<oldname, newname>
Dim renameMethod = Sub(kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) File.Move(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
' either sequential rename ...
For Each newName In newNames
    renameMethod(newName)
Next
' ... or it could be multi threaded
Parallel.ForEach(newNames, renameOperation)
```

Notes:

- File.Exists check is unnecessary based on the rename rule using the file index. If you change the rule it may be necessary. The rule is ambiguous in your question body. This assumes it's only run once.
- Dictionary keys will be unique since Windows won't have duplicate filenames

To answer your question, `Will it be possible to rename these files in one operation[?]`, no, but we can do it in one "line", with multiple threads, even. Just modify the path string "c:\path\with\files" and run this code

```
Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles("c:\path\with\files").OrderBy(Function(s) File.GetLastWriteTime(s)).Select(Function(s, i) New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(s, Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(s), $"{Path.GetFileName(s)(0)}_{i}{Path.GetExtension(s)}"))), Sub(kvp) File.Move(kvp.Key, kvp.Value))
```

I think you may need to work out your renaming logic. That is why I had separated it in the long code sample. Just work on the logic inside `newNameSelector`.

If you want to order by name, simply

```
Dim orderedFilenames = filenames.OrderBy(Function(s) s)
```

This will remove "_20190607" from your filename

```
Dim newNameSelector =
    Function(s As String)
        Return New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(s,
            Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(s), String.Format("{0}{1}", Path.GetFileName(s).Split("_"c)(0), Path.GetExtension(s))))
    End Function
```

I know this answer is getting hughmungus, but OP keeps providing new info, which means the question is morphing, thus so is the answer. According to his most recent comment, only the earliest of each prefix should be renamed.

```
' group the filenames into groups using key: "prefix_"
Dim groupedFilenames = Directory.GetFiles("c:\path\with\files").GroupBy(Function(s) Path.GetFileName(s).Split("_"c)(0))
Dim filenames As New List(Of String)()
' add the min from each group, using the name as the comparer
For Each g In groupedFilenames
    filenames.Add(g.Min(Function(s) s))
Next
' rename the files into a dictionary<oldname, newname>
' will result in filename X_Y.Z where X is first letter, Y is order index, Z is extension
Dim newNameSelector =
    Function(s As String)
        Return New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(s,
            Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(s), String.Format("{0}{1}", Path.GetFileName(s).Split("_"c)(0), Path.GetExtension(s))))
    End Function
' get new names using the newNameSelector function
Dim newNames = filenames.Select(newNameSelector)
' define the operation to rename the file using a keyvaluepair<oldname, newname>
Dim renameOperation = Sub(kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) File.Move(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
' ... or it could be multi threaded
Parallel.ForEach(newNames, renameOperation)
```

Comment: thank for your reply I did not get your code I want simple code to handle my case I am beginner in ASP.NET VB, please explain more details so I can make sure that the code work

Comment: @Mahmoud make sure you read my answer. It has details in comments on almost every line.

Comment: thank you I will do it but in your code the $ sign is not possible character also is there a way to order the files by name?

Comment: @Mahmoud You might be using an older version of Visual Studio and .NET framework. You can change `$"{Path.GetFileName(s)(0)}_{i}{Path.GetExtension(s)}"` to `String.Format("{0}_{1}{2}", Path.GetFileName(s)(0), i, Path.GetExtension(s))`

Comment: awesome its work but you did not answer my second question if i want to order the files by name is it possible ?

Comment: also please let me know how to use rename operation property in the last line

Comment: Original file received with timestamp like this : 1)customer_20190607 2)commodity_20190607 3)vendor_20190607 and what I need exactly is to get the new file name as 1)customer 2)commodity 3)vendor without timestamp is it possible?

Comment: @Mahmoud I made the changes you requested

Comment: That's great different thread should be placed for each file right? As I have three different file with different name

Comment: If you have three files, the overhead of multi-threading will most likely cause the operation to take longer than just doing it sequentially. Maybe you're talking about something else?

Comment: In my example I show you three file name each one with different name what I need exactly is to select the first file named customer_20190607(timestamp changed everyday) then change it like customer (remove timestamp) what should I do in this case? It's not sequentially, also I don't have enough experience with multi threading

Comment: Ok, see my edit. This had better answer it because it's my last one.

Comment: Thanks but what about other files? I informed you that I have three files with different name

Comment: @Mahmoud your comment `Original file received with timestamp like this : 1)customer_20190607 2)commodity_20190607 3)vendor_20190607 and what I need exactly is to get the new file name as 1)customer 2)commodity 3)vendor without timestamp is it possible?` is already satisfied. Please try out the code above